# Python web scraping script resources needed for cloud computing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, heroku, google-cloud-platform

I have a python script for doing web scraping, that it's imposible to run it in my computer due harward limitations. I was wondering, for run it in the cloud with google app engine or Heroku, using -if it's possible, the freeware resources both provie- and the first questions arise me is:

How could i know if my script stay under freeware limitations?
How could i know the harware resources needed?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As posed, this question is off-topic. But you can start by choosing a specific cloud hosting service and looking at its documentation to see what (if anything) it offers for free.

Answer (score 0):

For Google Cloud, there's a [free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/always-free-usage-limits) so if you stay under that, it's free.

I am not sure why you need to "know" if your app stays in the free range, you can simply try it and see if it stays in the free range. It would be too difficult to guess if you would stay in the free range without know your application and expected traffic. What you can do is simply try it and set a very low or zero [budget](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets#view_edit_or_delete_a_budget) to prevent being charged too much.

Answer (score 0):

I think in that context you can go with Alibaba cloud. Using Alibaba Cloud Free trial you can subscribe an ECS instance for a month. In this way, you can avoid charges. Please have a look at [Official Document](https://www.alibabacloud.com/getting-started/projects/alibaba-cloud-new-user-free-trial) which provides step by step process to create, enrol free account and how to subscribe an ECS instance. You can try the python script there without any restriction and limits for a month.